# iMovie built in music and audio effects missing

Tags: macos, imovie, final-cut-pro

This problem also happens to me in Final Cut. Since one week or so, the common audio effects and music clips are missing. I have removed these two applications, rebooted the computer and installed again iMovie, with the same results. Any idea?

Comment: I know it won't help, but that is a lesson for life: never use plugins, built in effects, presets and templates. I can restore projects from almost 20 years, because I manage every asset (including fonts) manually.

Comment: Finally I fixed it by upgrading to Big Sur.